# Streamlit Autocomplete from list of values

Tags: python, autocomplete, streamlit

I want to provide suggestions / autocomplete based on a list of values in text_input in streamlit

```
text_input(label = "select location", max_chars=200, placeholder=" 
<enter_country_name>", autocomplete = [some list of value])
```

However, I get that the error can be only accepted b or string then how can we suggest something as below

e.g. if write Del -> Delhi
similarly, if write Kol -> Kolkata

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? If you get error then show it in question (not in comments) as text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi updated as requested

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this custom made tool that enables autocomplete from searches, not select boxes: https://github.com/m-wrzr/streamlit-searchbox

Comment: Does this support to be used with columns

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this with `st.text_input`. Right now the only way is using `st.selectbox` ou `st.multiselect`.

Using `st.selectbox` you'll have to pass a sequence of options. The user will be able to select one of them OR type a *keyword* in the selectbox. Along the typing all the options that matches what user is typing will be shown.

[image]

Same goes for `st.multiselect`.

Answer (score 0):

this is already there in selectbox in streamlit. 
https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.selectbox